# Getting twice the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out what's happening here. When I select the `$('#semestre')` option, everything works perfectly. Then I select the `$('#turma')` option and change its value. Everything works. Then, I change the `$('#semestre')` value again, and everything works. However, when I change again the `$('#turma')` value, I get the alert twice. And if I do it again, I get three times the alert and so on. What am I missing here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.turma').hide();
    $('#semestre').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            $('.options_turma').remove();
            $('.turma').show();
            $.post('seleciona_turmas.php', {cd_turma: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                var item;
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                $.each(data.json, function(){
                    item = "<option class='options_turma' value='" + this['codigo'] + "'>" + this['descricao'] + "</option>";
                    $('#turma').append(item);
                });

                $('#turma').change(function(){
                    if($(this).val() != ''){
                        alert("OK");
                    }else{
                        alert('NULL');
                    }
                });
            });
        }else{
            $('#turma').val('');
            $('.turma').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to be clear, but it's a confusing question.

Comment: You are attaching the handler multiple times. Each time the `semestre` change handler runs it attaches *another* change handler to `turma`

Comment: @Matt Burland But then why doesn't the alert show up when semestre changes? ;s I need to change    semestre    value to that happen, then it happens twice :/

Comment: @user3260711 - because you're not alerting anything when `semestre` changes.

Comment: @Matt Burlan Ok.. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the change event ***every time*** you change the `semestre` dropdown. Pull the `#turma` event out of the `semestre` change event.

Like this

```
$('#semestre').change(function() {
    //Semestre code
});

$('#turma').change(function(){
    //Turma code
});
```

Comment: I tried, it didn't fix my problem :/ Where should I put this? I just replaced this part

Comment: @user3260711 - look at my updated answer. It needs to come out of the 1st change event & become a separate event.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the .change event on #turma tag must be out of .change event on #semestre tag

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#turma').on('change', function() {
  // ....
});
```

Comment: How is that different from what OP already has? `.change()`  is just a shorthand for `on('change')`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click